# Parital view show login page with fullsite if session out after computer left idle for long time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have created an asp.net mvc razor application, in which I load a partial view in a div, which can be accessed after login.

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Showproducts", "Home", new AjaxOptions {
    UpdateTargetId = "resdiv", OnBegin = "fstart()", OnSuccess = "fend()"
}, new { id = "_myform" }))
{ %>
    .....
<% } %>
```

When a user leaves their computer for a long time (which makes the session time out automatically) and then clicks the submit button, the resdiv is filled with the full site with the login panel. I want to show the full site with login panel NOT in the resdiv. Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

Yes, there is a way. I would recommend you reading the [`following blog post`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) in which Phil Haack illustrates a very nice technique allowing you to override the Forms Authentication Module for AJAX requests and be able to send a 401 status code instead of redirecting to the login page.

Then on the client side you could use a [`global AJAX handler`](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) where you could test the status code and if it is 401 redirect to the logon page.

For example once you have installed the `AspNetHaack` NuGet you could add the following global error handler to your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
        if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
            // not authenticated => redirect to login page:
            window.location.href = '@FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl';
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I had to add the SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule class to the App_start.FormsAuthenticationConfig.cs to get this to work.  Also that class I had to add: using System;
I added the error handler from Darin to my _Layout.cshtml.